# What are MOO2 ship designs good for defending planets?

Tags: master-of-orion-2

Most Master of Orion 2 guides I have seen focus on just a few typical ship designs like:

- classic beam ship
- classic hit and run missile carrier
- classic assault ship with much defense and star troopers that is used to capture enemy ships

What are some ship designs good for defending planets together with star bases / battle stations / star fortresses + on-planet defensive structures like planetary missile bases / fighter garrisons / ground batteries?

I was thinking about a ship with good defense and torpedos (since they are unlimited, unlike missiles), but this is just a preliminary thought.

Any other creative designs good for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic beam ship or missile/fighter carriers are best. You do not want dedicated defensive ships. Fleet limit is precious and spending any on purely defensive ships is a waste.

The normal ship design work well enough in defense and are better at offense, so you can better run a counterattack.

Comment: I'd mostly agree with this, although I do often have a specialist ship designed to board and capture ships (scrapping captured Antaran ships can give you Antaran tech).

Comment: @JonK Well, assault vessels can also be used offensively, they are just worse than damage ships against other races, as you rarely care about their vessels and assualt ships are riskier to use.